# How to get value from module, returns undefined value

Tags: node.js

I am trying to return a random number from the random-number-csprng API and it sends the value to the console, but not outside of the module. How can I compare the value from the module inside another module?

I have tried to return the number parameter from the .then() function but it still does not get outside of the function.

```
const Promise = require("bluebird");
const randInt = require("random-number-csprng");

class project {
    constructor(uname) {
        this.uname = uname;
    }

    randomNumber(lowest, highest)
    {
        Promise.try(() => {
            return randInt(lowest, highest);
        }).then(number => {
            console.log("Your random number:", number);
        }).catch({code: "RandomGenerationError"}, err => {
            console.log("Something went wrong!");
        });
    }

    checkRandom()
    {
        console.log(`This is a test: ${this.randomNumber(1,100)}`);

        if(this.randomNumber(1, 100) > 1)
        {
            console.log(`Works!`);
        }
        else
        {
            console.log(`Does not work!`);
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
This is a test: undefined
Your random number: 65
Your random number: 71
```

I expected the output to be 65 on the undefined log, but seems like it does not get stored outside of the `Promise.try()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you followed the example code on their documentation a bit too literally. You need to return the promise from the method, and consume it asynchronously by [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)ing it:

```
const randInt = require('random-number-csprng');

class Project {
  constructor(uname) {
    this.uname = uname;
  }

  randomNumber(lowest, highest) {
    return randInt(lowest, highest);
  }

  async checkRandom() {
    const randomValue = await this.randomNumber(1,100);

    console.log(`This is a test: ${randomValue}`);

    if (randomValue > 1) {
      console.log('Works!');
    } else {
      console.log('Does not work!');
    }
  }
}
```